# Expected type-specifier before 'PCLPlotter'

Tags: debugging, plot, types

I'm trying to use PCLPlotter to plot some data points. However, when I try to initialize two PCLPlotters, I get an `error:expected type-specifier before 'PCLPlotter'` for the line `pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter* linplotter = new PCLPlotter("lin acc");`. I get the same error for another PCLPlotter. I added `#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_plotter.h>` at the top as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question. But probably you forgot adding the namespace `pcl::visualization::` before `PCLPlotter("lin acc")`?